# *_attributes=() fails validation for nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Original title: before_validation on update - not handling error properly

I'm trying to figure out how to handle the validation of a nested object, especially on the update.

My parent class that handles the nested attributes.

**meeting.rb**

```
has_many :proposed_times, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :meeting
validates_associated :proposed_times
accepts_nested_attributes_for :proposed_times
...
def proposed_times_attributes=(attributes)
  attributes.each do |key,value|
    value[:timezone] = timezone
    if value[:id]
      p = ProposedTime.find(value[:id])
      value.delete(:id)
      p.update_attributes(value)
    else
      self.proposed_times << ProposedTime.new(value)
    end
  end
end
```

The class I'm trying to validate is below. Basically I need to validate that the date is in the future. And I'm constructing my starting_at with a `before_validation` method. So I'm not sure how to handle the case that (A) it can't properly construct the date (in the case where the user deletes the date I need to tell the user to fill it in) (B) If I do construct it, then it fails the save, I don't know how to get it to go back to the view to correct the information.

**proposed_times.rb**

```
belongs_to :meeting, :inverse_of => :proposed_times
validate :future_enough
before_validation :construct_starting_at
...
def future_enough
  unless starting_at && starting_at >= (Time.now + 15.minutes)
    errors.add(:not_far_enough_out, "msg not used but: starting_at isn't far enough out")
  end
end

def construct_starting_at
  if date.present? && time.present? && timezone.present?
    begin
      d = Time.parse(date)
      self.starting_at = Time.zone.parse("#{d.year}-#{d.month}-#{d.day} #{time.hour}:#{time.min}:00 #{timezone}")
    rescue
      self.starting_at = nil
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the view I'm using. I know this isn't the best way to handle this functionality, but I'm working with what I have… Everything I do redirects to `thank_you`. I'm not sure why it isn't failing on the save.

**meeting_controller.rb**

```
def propose_times
  @consultation = Consultation.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user

  # If this is coming second time around with data to save
  if request.put?
    @consultation.attributes = params[:consultation]
    if @consultation.save
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      render :layout => "simple"
    end
  else
    render :layout => "simple"
  end
end
```

What is the proper way for me to validate a nested object and handle the errors? Do I need to be using [`new_record?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F) for the `before_validation` method?

**Update**: So using @Aditya's suggestion of validates_associated, it still doesn't validate just the updated data. The updated times I put in get validated… but since they aren't valid, they aren't kept, and then it gets validated again (with the old data) and then that passes/fails validation and the warnings for those dates are shown.

What am I missing?

**Update 2**: I added a bunch of p statements to see the order of events and if I leave out the `validated_associated`, then it only gets validated once, but for some reason the meeting itself saves fine and therefore it redirects to thank you. But if I leave it in, it validates twice, hence the issues. So why is it validating the first (or second) time and how do I stop that?

**Update 3**: Ok, so I took out my `proposed_times_attributes=` function and in the view added the timezone there. This fixed the issue (along with @Aditya's method). I wish I knew how to get it to work with a defined method like that. I tried various other combinations of having/not having `validates_associated`, `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, and having that function defined.

SO if you come across this, and happen to know how to write `proposed_times_attributes=` so the validation would still work, please let me know.I need to be able to put timezone in `proposed_times_attributes=` because on view I would like to put one timezone select box for all of the proposed_times. I wish there was a way to call super() inside the `*_attributes=()` method.

Comment: Have you seen the :validates option when defining the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. So you can do a `super()`-type method  by calling [`assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association) or [`assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association). But you need to also call [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) in order to set some of the options for those methods (click on the function's name to see the documentation for each).

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :advisor, :client, :proposed_times
...
def proposed_times_attributes=(attributes)
  attributes.each do |key,value|
    value[:timezone] = client.timezone
  end
  assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(:proposed_times, attributes)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@RyanJM

You don't need to manually validate the child associate entities if you use the following

**meeting.rb**

```
validates_associated :proposed_times
```

assuming you already have the following association in your **meeting.rb**

```
has_many :proposed_times
```

Comment: I hadn't seen that. I just added it, but it still validates the updated data, fails, and then validates old data rather than just using the failed data. Any ideas why it would check it twice?